How do I convert my script into an executable including additional files?
If I use Pyinstaller or Auto-py-to-exe to try to convert my Python script into an .exe file, and I try to include images / the folder of the tkinter theme I am using, it is always telling me it couldn't find the data I tried to include.
These are both ways, I tried to load the images into my GUI (both working fine):
def resource_path(relative):
            return os.path.join(
                os.environ.get(
                    '_MEIPASS2',
                    os.path.abspath('.')
                ),
                relative
            )

            return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
#---------------------------------------------------------
def resource_path2(relative_path):
            try:
                base_path = sys.MEIPASS
            except Exception:
                base_path = os.path.abspath('.')
            
            return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

If I use Auto-py-to-exe for example, I give it all the additonal files I need (theme folder with the theme images inside, the theme .tcl file, and my two .png files which are used in the GUI).
When running the command auto-py-to-exe gives me, I don't run into any errors whatsoever... the .exe file is getting created in the dist folder. Now when I try to start the .exe file, I will always get the error, that the image couldn't be found in the specific path (in which it definitly is).
If I add all my additonal files to the dist folder, in which my .exe is, it is running perfectly. I have also watched various tutorials und read through articles but nothing helped.

what was the command you ran?

can you also provide your folder structure?

I would recommend using pyinstaller for this. Here is a link to the documentation that shows you how to bundle additional files with the exe: https://pyinstaller.org/en/v3.3/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

resource_path() will not work.  resource_path2() will work if sys._MEIPASS is used instead of sys.MEIPASS.

@iBeMeltin I've ran 'pyinstaller --onefile --console --icon=example.ico --add-data src;picture.png

If you provide your folder structure with all the files you need added to the exe I can provide an answer

@iBeMeltin My file path is:  C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Project1\logoWhite.png                               Project1 is the folder where my main script and my files are stored.

see my answer below

I recommend using the cx_freeze library.
It allow you to configure everything you need and to build it pretty easily, with lib and files import.
More information Here
Write all the following in a Setup.py file
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "My_exe with cx_freeze",
    version = "1.2",
    description = "Your programm description",
    executables = [Executable("script.py", base="Win32GUI",targetName="My_exe")],
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "includes": ["PIL.Image","PIL.ImageTk"],
            'include_files': ['grv2.ico','gv3.png','no_image.png',"image2test.png"],
            "packages": [ "tkinter"],
            "optimize":1,
        }}
)


To build the Exe you need to run this command
python setup.py build
I know it dont use the library that your tried but it's an efficient and clear way to create an Exe with additionnal file.

I do not know your exact folder structure, but to add a file to an exe with pyinstaller you use the following command:
pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "source_path;destination_path"
if you want multiple files:
pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "file1.txt;." --add-data "folder1;folder1" --add-data "file2.txt;." your_script.py
For reference, in the last command:
file1.txt;. adds file1.txt to the root of the bundle.
folder1;folder1 adds the entire folder1 directory to the bundle.
file2.txt;. adds file2.txt to the root of the bundle.

Now when you access them in your script you use your function:
def get_resource_path(relative_path):

    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

and :
file1_path = resource_path("file1.txt")
folder1_path = resource_path("folder1")
file2_path = resource_path("file2.txt")

